# Is it possible to get Outlook's identity so that my addin can send bulk emails without outlook being busy

Tags: c#, email, outlook, smtp, outlook-addin

I have been looking for this from some time now with no success. 
We are considering a solution if at all possible. For example, there may be 1K+ emails to be sent via our Outlook add-in (written in C#), now If I use outlook's email functionality, Outlook gets busy sending emails one by one and during this time, Outlook can't send/receive other emails.
I'm not sure if we can do this, but can we get the identity of outlook so that add-in can send emails on Outlook's behalf and Outlook doesn't get busy.
I haven't found any details regarding this yet, does the security model of Outlook allows such a workaround?

We don't want to connect using SMTP and storing user credentials as Gmail doesn't provide access to supposedly less secure apps.
Creating an app around Gmail or any other provider's APIs may be a solution, but I want to know if what I'm asking for is possible or not?

Any suggestions/pointers/insights will be highly appreciated.

Comment: if the emails are all the same, can you use the BCC field and populate it with all of the email addresses (or as many as will fit), sending one email to 1000 addresses? If the contents are all going to be different though, you might be out of luck. You can use gmail with the less secure app, you just need to allow them in the gmail settings. Also, you can still use 2 factor authentication by setting up an application password.

Comment: Once the messages are submitted and are being transmitted, Outlook will not block the UI. Do you mean Outlook is blocked while your code is creating the messages?

Comment: @user1666620 We are using all emails addresses in bcc field, and the email template is same.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko No the outlook UI doesn't block, but it can't send and receive any mail during this time.

Comment: No, I don't think there is anything you can do - while the messages are being submitted, Outlook won't do send/receive on the same account.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko Exactly! That's why I was asking if I could somehow get Outlook's identity on programming side, which would manifest itself as outlook and would send mails.So far, I have come to the conclusion that it can't be achieved. Even if it was possible it would break the security model of outlook.

Comment: If making outlook not busy is your motto, then try using smtp to send mails instead of interop.